# failed to find Build Tools revision 21.1.1 - sdk up to date

Tags: android, linux, gradle, revision, build-tools

I´m running a linux android sdk installation and my new project needs Build tools 21.1.1

Somehow, this build tools do not exist, eventhough my sdk is up to date, but in the build-tools folder there is now android-4.4W folder

android update sdk --no-ui

[image]

My sdk/build-tools folder

[image]

I´ve moved the content testwise to a 21.1.1 folder, but this isn´t recognized either.

Is this a bug?How to I get the right build tools?

Comment: Android 4.4W is API-20. Concerning the build tools 21.1.1, If you say you have it in your SDK, I cannot help you more without more informations.

Comment: Thank you. I´ve updated the posting with a screenshot of the sdk-update result. As you can see, it tells me that everything is up to date. Which additional information do you need?

Comment: Do you have a `21.1.1` folder insode `<androidsdk>/build-tools/`? Seems to me like you don't (from your 2nd screenshot).

Comment: Nope, that is my problem ;)

Comment: I guess you are using the Android SDK from CLI. You are obviously missing the 21.1.1 build-tools. `android update sdk --no-ui` should do the work.

Comment: as I said and as the first sreenshot shows, everything is up to date when running this command

Comment: Obviously your Android SDK does NOT have build-tools 21.1.1. Try @Nachbar90 workaround.

Comment: Yes indeed, and I don´t know why it thought that it was up to date. Thank you anyway ;)

Comment: This was my answer, hope it will help:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/42010068/2862728

Answer (score 126, accepted):

What worked for me was:

```
android list sdk -a
```

Which showed me the following list:

```
1- Android SDK Tools, revision 24.0.2
2- Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 21
3- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.1.2
4- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.1.1
5- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.1
6- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.0.2
7- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.0.1
... and a great many more
```

Followed by the command:

```
android update sdk -a -u -t 3
```

The "3" in the command refers the the index listed in the output of the first command.

Comment: Bingo! I forgot I hid obsolete packages (that version is now), but all sample apps from sdk were referring to such. I was feeling lazy to adjust every sample I wanted to try:-)

Comment: Worked for me using react native complaining about `23.0.1`

Comment: I get a `Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
         Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.`

Answer (score 31):

Solved it by using

> android update sdk -u -a

where the a parameter installs all packages. Not the best solution to install everything, but it has at least installed the required build tools version

Comment: Then if required build tools is not present, You have to install that using Android SDK Manager

Comment: this command is the linux equivalent to the sdk manager, and it does exactly what you say, installing the build tools in the latest version

Comment: watch out, this definetly will consume a lot of your HD

Comment: If one were to do this, how would one go about removing unneeded packages?

Comment: You can delete them manually. I've deleted all images, emulator stuff and samples at least. This freed a lot of space

Answer (score 30):

I was getting this error on my Jenkins too:

> failed to find Build Tools revision 21.1.2

Instead of getting all Android SDK updates, I just needed to:

## Get **Build Tools revision 21.1.2**

```
sudo android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-21.1.2
```

## Other commands I've used:

Help:

```
sudo android update sdk --help
```

Get list of available Android SDK updates:

```
sudo android list sdk --extended --all
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, and i could fix it by launching Android SDK Manager in Android Studio and install the Build Tools by checking the option.

Comment: With the gui there is no problem at all. In my case I have no gui on my machine

Comment: Tick "Show Package Details" on bottom right corner to install specific version of "Android SDK Build Tools" under "SDK Tools" tab.

Answer (score -1):

In the error window where it displayes message as failed to find build tools versions, it also gives the link to install the tools version. You can update using that.

If the above option is not available then another way is: 
Open the sdk tools tab from sdk manager in android studio. Click on 'Launch StandAlone SDK Manager'. In the new widnow, you will be able to see all the revisions of build tools, api levels, system images. From there you can can select the tools revision which are missing and install.

Comment: this question is just about installing it from console. In Android-Studio, everything is okay. You can easily install the latest packages only from the SDK Manager, so thats not the point