# Qt compiler reports invalid build tools version for Android

Tags: android, qt

I have been developing Android applications using Eclipse/Android Studio. Now, I am exploring building an application using QT. I installed QT and configured it for Android as explained at http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt5ForAndroidBuilding. I later my first Android app using "QT Quick Application" template. When I compile it from QT Creator, I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\MyQtApps\build-MyTest1-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_8_Qt_5_4_1-Debug\android-build\build.gradle' line: 39

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android-build'.
> Invalid revision: build-tools-21.1.2
```

Android build tools version 21.1.2 is present on the machine. In fact, my SDK and all other Android tools are completely up to date.

Next, from the options dialog, I turned "Use Gradle" off and entered the path for Ant executable. After that, I proceeded to create a new project. This project builds and deploys fine on my mobile device.

Looks like the problem is with Gradle integration. For now, I can simply go with Ant but would be nice to have it fixed. Any suggestions? Regards.

Comment: Can you edit to indicate which resource\faq\wiki did you follow for the configuration setup? is your android sdk up to date? check the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272605/failed-to-find-build-tools-revision-21-1-1-sdk-up-to-date

Answer (score 2):

For those who are running into this problem (and I assume this includes everyone who is using Qt for Android development), the solution is to fix Qt-generated `gradle.properties` file. This file contains the following line:

```
 androidBuildToolsVersion=build-tools-21.1.2
```

File `build.gradle` tries to use this variable as:

```
android {
   ...
   buildToolsVersion androidBuildToolsVersion
   ...
}
```

Function `buildToolsVersion` expects a value such as `21.1.2` and not `build-tools-21.1.2`. So the fix is to edit `gradle.properties` file as:

```
 androidBuildToolsVersion=21.1.2
```

I still don't know where Qt Creator picks up 21.1.2 from. In my case, I used the following setting:

```
 androidBuildToolsVersion=23.0.0
```

Now, things work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33658061/5620997) solution:
You can change in the *android/gradle.properties* the *androidBuildToolsVersion* to the desired one.

Note: You have to edit the file via shell because it doesn't appear in the qt creator (at least in the 5.9 version)