# How to fix build tools (22.0.0/1) dependency issues

Tags: android, build-tools

Before last month, I have been using Eclipse for android development. But now I am trying to use android studio because of the google's policy.

I am so tired.

I ran across this error

[image]

I don't understand this message. Because I don't use "Build Tools revision 23.0.0 rc" I am using 22.0.0.

```
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"
```

But I met that's error continue. So I downloaded and Installed Build Tools 23.0.0 rc2. But I met network error.

[image]

Solutions please. I am tired.

Comment: Hi, :) Did you try deleting build tools 22 before adding build 23

Comment: Yes, I did your assist. I did deleting build tools 22, 23. And rebuild. Next I can see install 22 message. I did it. And... I can see install build tools 23 message. I hate Android Studio.

Comment: what happened after?

Comment: nooo its not the android studio.. its the SDK hahaha.. How'd it go now?

Comment: Same. 
I can't install Build Tools 23.0.0 rc2. Maybe we can't install yet 'build tools 23.0.0'
I really hate... :S

Comment: I really wanted to help you but I need to know 2 things. Where is Android SDK installed and where is "Install failed" showing

Comment: Thank you for your solution of Grammer issue. I uploaded install error screenshot.

Comment: @Sheychan. I did reinstall Android Studio. Luckly!!! I met same issue. I hate Android Studio.

Comment: solved it w8 for my answer

Comment: solved it?? are you genius?

Comment: w8 no picture came out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it happens because of build tools inconsistency. Firstly make sure 22 is installed then 23rc is not installed.

[image]

After that in your Android Studio Open Gradle Scripts >> build.gradle (Module:app). Make sure the installed build tool which is 22.0.1 in me is declared here. After changing the numbers make sure you rebuild/sync/refresh the project. And you are done. 
Note: Make sure this is done to all of your projects

[image]

Comment: Here it is please check

Comment: Its updated did you try already.. and did you rebuild the gradle?

Comment: I did according to your assist. install 22, delete 23 rc3, 4 But I can see same error.

Comment: Rebuildding project: Rebuild >> Rebuild project

Comment: oh............... sorry.
I used several library. That's used build tools 23..... :S
I solved it. Thank you @Sheychan !!!!

Comment: meaning you got multiple projects and you only edited the build config of 1 app? xD gonna edit

Comment: installing build-tools 22.0.1 worked for me on android-sdk 24.3.3

Answer (score 1):

I am new to the Android programming. But I now get this error.
On 8/28/2015, I have with the SDK Manager on the Android Studio (1.3.2 Build 141.2178183), while my current project was opened, installed new, previously not installed packages and also I have done other recommended update. Subsequently, I received the error message "Install Build Tool revision 23.0.0. rc2" and "Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g... Try Again Open 'Messages' View Show Log in Explorer".
I have tried it without success.

Uninstall/new  install Build-Tools in the SDK manager brought no change. There was a "Build Tools revsion 232.0 rc2" also not to be found.

Therefore, I have looked at the Grandle files accurately. The file build.gradle (Module: app) in 
C: \ Users \  \ AndroidStudioProjects \  \ app \ build.gradle contained the following entry:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"
```

I have changed this with an editor:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
```

Then I could call up the project again without errors and also perform a synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

I tried above solution it seemed not to work at first but try looking into all build files. For example if your project has got multiple modules say wearable module  or like update its gradle build file too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be answered perfectly here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28159380/3436166

Just install the required version of Build Tools and the dependency issue will be solved.