# React Native on Android failed to find Build Tools

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

What causes following problem? Is my Android SDK Version not supported?

```
Starting JS server...                                                                     
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                                  

* What went wrong:                                                                        
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.                                            
> failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.1
```

Comment: From v25 of SDK manager you now have to install the correct Build Tool from Android Studio because the `android` command is removed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44295114/82609

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Probably you need to update your Build Tools.

I faced the problem when I tried to update from the graphic interface, it didn't show the exact minor version, so I couldn't update to it.

It was solved by looking at the available versions from the terminal with:

```
android list sdk -a
```

```
[...]
Packages available for installation or update: 156
1- Android SDK Tools, revision 24.4
2- Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 23.0.1
3- Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 23.1 rc1
4- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23.0.1
```

[...]

And installing the right version with:

```
android update sdk -a -u -t 4
```

Comment: What is this `android` program? Where do I get it?

Comment: @jameshfisher it's part of the Android SDK, it's located at the "tools" directory for example: ~/android-sdk/tools/android

Comment: I tried updating with Android Studio several times, but it never worked. This command did though. Thank you.

Comment: It is in android-sdk-linux in react project actually.

Comment: Note in new versions of SDK manager the `android` command does not work anymore and one has to run Android Studio to access this setting see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44295114/82609

Answer (score 74):

Just a note - it's possible to get this error because the only version of the build tools you have installed is *too new*.

I got precisely the error that the OP got (complaining that react-native couldn't find Build Tools revision 23.0.1). When I checked my Android SDK Manager, I saw this:

[image: screenshot showing 23.0.2 "Installed" but 23.0.1 "Not installed"]

I'd naively thought that installing the latest version of the Build-tools (23.0.2 at the time of writing) would work, but apparently not. Additionally installing 23.0.1 fixed the problem.

Comment: same problem here. isn't there a way to use newer build tools? maybe some configuration.

Comment: This suggestion worked for me as well. 23.0.2 was too new, go figure. Thanks.

Comment: @boatcoder this answer (install older build tools) is no less correct than sodik's (modify `build.gradle` to make React Native use newer build tools). Android Build Tools seem to follow SemVer, so modifying `build.gradle` to use a later patch or minor version should usually be safe, may provide some platform-level bugfixes or performance improvements, and spares you having to download anything. *But* it will break your app if done on a *major* version release, and introduces *some* risk even with patch/minor releases since you're using RN with build tools that Facebook did not intend.

Answer (score 29):

I also had problem with newer version of SDK Build tools (same as Mark) but I managed to resolve it with modification of `android/app/build.gradle` and setting proper version, e.g.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
...
```

UPDATE: As Mark suggested, it is wise only update minor (or patch) version in this way. Another reason why **not** to update this version is when you have plenty of 3rd party libs with native part - you might end up updating all of them. So you must weight possible benefits of newer version vs a bit more work.

Comment: don't forget to change line 85 `targetSdkVersion 22` to `targetSdkVersion 23` as well.

Comment: I found that the generated build.gradle file had buildToolsVersion "23.0.1" but I only had version 23 (23.0.0) installed - Not sure where the "react-native init" finds the android/tools SDK version numbers from. So the cause is actually that the react-native init command is not using the available tools version number ?

Comment: I believe 23.0.1 is fixed (maybe can change with RN versions) but there is no detection afaik.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem, Changed from 23 to 25 and 23.0.1 to 25.0.0

Answer (score 4):

Need modify 4 files

> grep buildToolsVersion * -r | grep 23.0.1

```
Examples/Movies/android/app/build.gradle:    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
Examples/UIExplorer/android/app/build.gradle:    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
ReactAndroid/build.gradle:    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
local-cli/generator-android/templates/src/app/build.gradle:    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to change my Android project's `build.gradle` to:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.demoproject"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It means that the Android Build Tools installed on your system is something else than in your app's configuration file (your configuration file is pointing to 23.0.1) but you probably have 23, 24 or 25.0.* on your system.

**The solution to fixing this problem:**

1. Edit the `build.gradle` file located under `anroid/app` in your project folder
2. Look for the entry `buildToolsVersion` "23.0.1", and replace it with the latest version you have on your system. You can find it here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools`

**OR** you could try to install in your system the version that you have in the `build.gradle` file (with SDK manager).

Answer (score 1):

If you have Build Tools version 24.0.1, then update your `build.gradle` to match `buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"`

My `Android/Sdk/build-tools/24.0.1/source.properties` had `Pkg.Revision` set to `24.0.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Find the version number in the `/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools` directory, and then modify the version number of the `buildToolsVersion` corresponding to the Gradle configuration

Answer (score 1):

From Android SDK manager v25 you have to install the correct build tools directly from Android Studio because the `android` command does not work anymore:

[image: install from android studio]

Comment: To get to this screen from within Andriod Studio.
file -> settings -> Android SDK -> SDK Tools -> bottom right "Show Package Details"

I added this comment as it took me a while to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem trying to build at the command line following react native's documentation.  I resolved this problem by opening the project in android studio.  The mismatched dependencies will appear in the build failure snackbar at the bottom of the App.  For each failure, click on the link to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it also happens if you uninstalled some packages from your react-native project and there is still packages in your build gradle dependencies in the bottom of page like:

`{
     project(':react-native-sound-player')
 }`

Make sure to remove the associated code in the MainApplication.java file after removing the project(':react-native-sound-player')