# How to get react-native init to use most recent version of build tools

Tags: react-native

When I created an app using "react-native init MyApp", it created files that specify build tools version 23.0.1. I ended up with the same problem as this person:

[React Native on Android failed to find Build Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155087/react-native-on-android-failed-to-find-build-tools)

23.0.1 is an older version of the build tools, and I'm thinking I should use the most recent one. I did a search for the term "23.0.1" in the project, and found that that version is specified not only in the top-level build.gradle, but also in all of the modules under /node_modules.

Questions:

- If I fix the top-level build.gradle, do I have to fix all the modules as well?
- Is there a command line react-native init param I can use to do it automatically? (I can't find documention on it.)
- Or should I not use the more recent versions and just install 23.0.1?

(I'm developing on Windows 10, if that matters.)

Comment: just install 23.0.1 - you might run into dependency issues if you use a different version