# React Native Install Error

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am consistently running into the same error when I run "react-native run-android." Here is the error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.1
```

I tried this --> [failed to find Build Tools revision 21.1.1 - sdk up to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272605/failed-to-find-build-tools-revision-21-1-1-sdk-up-to-date) --> and got the same error.

I installed the android sdk with homebrew and my ANDROID_HOME export is in my .bash_profile and .zshrc file as:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk
```

When I go to this directory and look in the "build-tools" directory I do see 23.0.1.

Does anyone have any advice?

**EDITS:**

I'm also unable to run "react-native run-android" with any flags. I'm not seeing any output from stacktrace, info or debug.

[image]

Comment: can you post a snapshot of the packages you see installed when you run `android`?

Comment: @IsaacMadwed, added above

Comment: I had this error too, but installing the build tools fixed it for me. I would try removing them, restarting, then reinstalling them

Comment: @MaxBaldwin do you got any solution????

Comment: @Akshay, I came up with an answer. Please see below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally figured it out! Chris Geirman's answer is also valuable, so I would start there as I did. One thing to mention is that I installed React Native with Homebrew. If Chris's method does not work look into the following:

1. Go to your React Native project directory that is created by `react-native init`
2. Open the `android` directory.
3. Open the file `local.properties`If you don't have this file you can make one.
4. Make sure the `sdk.dir` value is pointing to the correct directory. In my case the path need to be `sdk.dir = /usr/local/opt/android-sdk`

As an extra bit of reassurance I also located that directory above to make sure that the build tools version that was missing (23.0.1) was in that directory.

**EDIT:**

I found that this is a post install error. If you run `react-native init` and you don't have `$ANDROID_HOME` set, you will run into this error.

Comment: great to know, and good find! out of curiosity, why did you choose to install via homebrew? and would a new `react-native init` require the same fix every time?

Comment: @ChrisGeirman, just ran a test. This seems to be a post install error. I deleted my directory that ```react-native init``` created and ran it again. Looks like it picked up on the ```$ANDROID_HOME``` variable the second time. I will add that as a note.

Comment: This didn't quite resolve it for me. In the end I also had to go into the *standalone* SDK manager and add the 23.0.1 build-tools.  Just checking 23 in Android Studio isn't enough to get it to install the *build-tools* for 23.0.1.  Note: Setting the env var before generating the app still required me to manually write the local.properties also.

Answer (score 1):

I found this in the book *Learning React Native* and thought you might find this quote helpful.

> If you receive a warning about a missing package, run android and check to see if
>   that package is listed as “installed”. If not, install it. If it is installed, but React Native
>   can’t find it, follow the steps above to try and fix any issues with your development
>   environment. You should also check to make sure that your `ANDROID_HOME` environ‐
>   ment variable is properly set and points to your installation of the Android SDK. For
>   example, on my system:

```
$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/usr/local/opt/android-sdk
```

Comment: I did the echo and my path is correct. I am going to try to uninstall some of the installed packages to see what happens. For future reference do you have a link to that book? Also does it say anything else?

Comment: Haha, it says lots more, but little more related to this issue. Here's a link http://shop.oreilly.com/product/mobile/0636920041511.do

Comment: Reinstalled the build tools, no dice. Is there anything Android that I need to be running while I run the react-native command?

Comment: I'm only just beginning to play with Android, but I always start VirtualBox, then the VM server within VirtualBox, then Genymotion. From the terminal, in the project's root, I run `react-native start` to start the packages, then `react-native run-android`

Comment: Yeah my virtual box is running with Genymotion. Still no dice. I tweeted this question at react, so hopefully they will chime in. Thanks for the time!

Comment: Maybe hit the Android channel up more aggressively

Comment: Chris, I found an answer. Thought you might be interested.