# My Android apps cant run, due to an "adb not responding" error

Tags: android, adb

Yesterday I updated my Android studio as well as downloaded new sdk to support different android versions among other things. After the update, I couldn't get my apps to run, I get the following errors.

First I get this error

[image]

Then This happens
[image]

Any idea how i can get out of this?
I'm using a MAC with the max osx 10.6.8. Thought that may help.

EDIT:

Further, when I open the "Android device monitor", I get the error "Unable to detect adb version, adb output"..

and when I rebuild the project I get this "Gradle sync failed: failed to find Build Tools revision 21.1.2"

Comment: I tried to reinstall Android Studio AND install all sdk tools. Still i get this error. Does anyone have any more ideas. This is getting quite frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

**Tools** > **Android** > **(Uncheck) Enable ADB Integration** (if studio hangs/gets stuck end adb process manually)

then,

**Tools > Android > (Check) Enable ADB Integration**

check [adb error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26431991/2826147) answer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: have you tried from link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431972/android-studio-lollipop-adb-genymotion-issues-devices-wont-show-up-adb/26431991#26431991

Comment: let me give it a try

Comment: In the very beginning, the command "killall -9 adb" tells me "No matching processes belonging to you were found" what does this mean?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/441004/error-running-bash-script-no-matching-processes

Comment: in directory of android studio

Comment: check this solution for EDIT ___ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272605/failed-to-find-build-tools-revision-21-1-1-sdk-up-to-date