# Error in xml After Adding Google Map Activity

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am getting following error :

> Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'. in values
>   v-23.xml

Here is my gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ashwin_bhoyar.techtt"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name

Answer (score 1):

> No resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'

You should call **API Level 23**

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ashwin_bhoyar.techtt"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

And use

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. i Get following error :Error:failed to find Build Tools revision 23.1.0
<a href="install.build.tools">Install Build Tools 23.1.0 and sync project</a>     I have updated in sdk manager to 23.1

Comment: @ashwinbhy really ? `Clean-Rebuild-Restart-Sync`

Comment: what about `buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"`

Comment: @ashwinbhy go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name

Comment: sorry amiya  in my sdk no buildToolsVersion 23.0.0 its 23.0.2 i have installed it

Comment: @ashwinbhy same problem for `23.0.2 ` ?

Comment: call  minSdkVersion 19

Comment: call `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'`

Comment: same error amiya : failed to find Build Tools revision 23.1.0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272605/failed-to-find-build-tools-revision-21-1-1-sdk-up-to-date

Comment: @ashwinbhy Facing same problem yet ?

Answer (score 1):

Please add this to your **gradle**.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
```

Hope this would work

Answer (score 0):

I edited your gradle code ............try to this,I hope's its works

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ashwin_bhoyar.techtt"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your compile SDK version must match the support library's major version.

Since you are using version 23 of the support library, you need to compile against version 23 of the Android SDK.

Alternatively you can continue compiling against version 21 of the Android SDK by switching to the latest support library v21.

**Please check The highlighted Part Of image**
[image: Update Your SDK Version For using..'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'. in values v-23.xml]

Comment: For more Info... please check it.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name