# Cordova Android Build Failure ("failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.1")

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I'm having trouble building my Cordova project with Android. When I typed "cordova build Android", this is the result:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.1
```

I checked my SDK manager and the build tools version 24.0.1 are installed. I was building earlier just fine so I'm not sure what changed. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This solution solved it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28159380/6697670.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by making sure that your PATH environment/system variable includes paths to the various Android tools, and also that you have an ANDROID_HOME entry pointing to the SDK

Partial PATH example (on Windows):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;
```

ANDROID_HOME example (on Windows):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
```

Comment: Thank you, that is a good suggestion but unfortunately it did not fix the issue for me.